# Add Parent to List of Subpages

Tags: wp-list-pages

This code works well to display child pages of the parent page while viewing both the parent page and child page.  It doesn't apply the `current_page_item` CSS class to the parent while viewing it (and only it, not interested in it being applied while on the children) - any suggestions?

```
<ul class="subpages">
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) {
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, it is trickier than it should be to get it working.

```
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
  $pages = get_pages(array('child_of'=>$parent));
  if (!empty($pages)) {
    $page_ids = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
      $page_ids[] = $page->ID;
    }
    $children = wp_list_pages("include=".$parent.','.implode(',',$page_ids)."&echo=1");
    echo '<ul>'.$children.'</ul>'; 
  }
}
```

You have to get a list of all of your pages and pass them in the `include` parameter. [The basic technique is listed in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_parent_Page_and_all_descendant_Pages). The above is nearly a copy, in fact.

That will give you `current_page_ancestor` on all ancestor pages and `current_page_parent` on the immediate parent only. That should be sufficient.

If you notice I have included the top-level parent in the page list. Your code only does that sometimes. I don't know if that is by design or not, but I included it. You should be able to add or remove that page to match whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem
Try it

1.[get_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page)

2.[get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

```
    <style>
    .current-menu-item a {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <ul class="subpages">
    <?php
        if($post->post_parent){
            $children = get_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent);
            $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
            $link = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
        }
        else{
            $children = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
            $parent_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $parent_page = $post->ID;
        }
        if ($children) {
        ?>
            <li <?php if( !empty($parent_page) && $parent_page==$post->ID){echo 'class="current-menu-item"';} ?>><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
            <?php 
                foreach( $children as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
            ?>
                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID)){echo 'class="current-menu-item"';} ?>>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php 
                endforeach;
            ?>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

**3.Note:Remove css style at top of my code when your test complete and apply your own css code.**

Comment: Sorry, this one doesn't work.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: i edited my code, working on my localserver try it..