# Add Parent to Subpage List

Tags: wp-list-pages

Below is the best code I could find for producing a list of subpages *and* the parent page.  However, it only shows the parent page while on the subpages.  How do I get this to display the parent page when the user is on the parent page also?

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent){
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
} else {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
}
if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="subpages">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: As near as I can tell the [code I gave you earlier today](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99900/21376) does what you describe. How is the behavior of that code different from what you want to achieve here?

Comment: may be you find your solution here  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98913/add-parent-to-list-of-subpages/99901#99901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
 if($post->post_parent){
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
 } else {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
 }

 if ($children) { ?>
   <ul class="subpages">
     <?php echo $children; ?>
   </ul>
 <?php } ?>
```

Try that.  Just have to include the parent much like you do on the child pages, but using the current $post-ID.