# Show links to child pages on both parent AND child pages

Tags: query

I have a client who wants the following;

They have a series of pages, each of which have children. On the parent pages they want to show links to all the children. For this I am currently using this query;

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $system_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($system_query->have_posts()) : $system_query->the_post();
?>

    <!-- links to all this page's children -->

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

This works fine for the parent pages, but now the client wants to show the same set of links to show on the child pages aswell...

Is there a simple way to amend this query to allow that? Or will I have to write something else from scratch

Comment: [Check this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98913/add-parent-to-list-of-subpages/99901#99901) link may be your solution

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work nicely for me;

```
<?php
    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
    if( count( $children ) != 0 ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $id = $post->post_parent;
    }
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $system_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($system_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($system_query->have_posts()) : $system_query->the_post();
?>

    <!-- list of child pages here -->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_rest_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: This will only work if your child pages are only a single level deep. Have a look at the [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) function for a simpler (and less memory-intensive) method.